# Class deconstructor is not working dotNET 7

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote such a class with a deconstructor.  But I get an error on this line: `(string model) = car;`

```
var car = new Car();
car.model = "GLE";
(string model) = car;
Console.WriteLine(model);
```

The car class is defined as:

```
public class Car
{
    public string model = "undefined";

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(model);
    }

    public void Deconstruct(out string model)
    {
        model = this.model;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tuple must have more than one element, and as such your declaration on line 3 is not valid